# C# SQL data to label control?

Tags: c#, sql

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working? I don't get an error in the code, but the information (month, day) doesn't show up in the labels. The connection is active, the data is there. It just will not display.

The listbox (listNames) is populated from the database, and that works fine. What I want is for the MONTH and DAY information from the selected record from listbox to display as labels.

Thanks for any help.

```
private void listNames_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Name = " + listNames.SelectedItem.ToString(), connection))
    {
        DataTable showlistTable = new DataTable();
        DataSet info = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(showlistTable);
        adapter.Fill(info);

        labelDetailsMonth.Text = info.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Month"].ToString();
        labelDetailsDay.Text = info.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Day"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you certain this code is being executed? Is there a chance the event is not wired up properly? Have you set a break point? Do you get any rows back if it does run?

Comment: Yes, check the values in the datatable you get back.  Set a breakpoint.  Do you need apostrophes?  Name = 'name'

Comment: The apostrophes need to be there, unless somehow listNames.SelectedItem.ToString() is accounting for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need single quotes around string literals in SQL (your `listNames.SelectedItem` value). The best way to do this is by avoiding the string literal entirely and using a query parameter. This will also fix the gaping sql injection security hole:

```
private void listNames_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE Name = @Name";
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection))
    {
        //guessing at column type/length here
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = listNames.SelectedItem;

        DataSet info = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(info);

        labelDetailsMonth.Text = info.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Month"].ToString();
        labelDetailsDay.Text = info.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Day"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there not a canonical “stop constructing SQL strings” answer? This gets asked so often.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. Unfortunately, this is still not populating the labels. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Joel Coehoorn - thank you, worked beautifully. I appreciate it!